# Outlook folders and sub-folders are all open when I start Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

All Outlook sub-folders are open when I start Outlook.  How can I change this, (disable).  I want all sub-folders closed when I start (open) Outlook.  And how do keep this setting as the default appearance every time I open Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of Outlook you can access your defined view templates in the following way:

- Outlook 2002/XP and previous
  View-> Current View-> Define Views…
- Outlook 2003
  View-> Arrange By-> Current View-> Define Views…
- Outlook 2007
  View-> Current View-> Define Views…
- Outlook 2010 
  tab View-> button Change View-> Manage Views…

You can reset outlook folders to default by:

- Windows XP
  Start-> Run; outlook.exe /cleanviews
- Windows Vista and Windows 7
  Start-> type; outlook.exe /cleanviews

Note: There is a space between `outlook.exe` and `/cleanviews`

More detail from:- [Applying custom views to all folders at once:](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/51)

Starting Outlook with [all folders collapsed/expanded](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/595)

In older versions the folders would open in the state they where closed in, [this could still be happening.](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t49689-expand-all-folders-in-outlook-2003-a.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset Outlook navigation pane (revert all user's customizations) and reload Outlook "form region definitions":

Close Outlook and run (in Windows Start > Run):

```
outlook.exe /resetnavpane
```

Re-arrange your outlook folders, close Outlook, and run:

```
outlook.exe /resetformregions
```

Open Outlook and your folders should be fine now.

BTW, here's a list of all command line switches for Outlook:

http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/commandlineswitches.htm